# sort multidimension array using one of the values while respecting its order php

Tags: php

I have this array, which is already sorted by 'name' ASC.

```
array 
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => '4'
      'name' => 'iPad'
      'games' => 5
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => '5'
      'name' => 'iPhone'
      'games' => 5
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => '6'
      'name' => 'Nintendo DS'
      'games' => 5
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => '1'
      'name' => 'Playstation 2'
      'games' => 2
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => '7'
      'name' => 'Playstation 3'
      'games' => 2
  5 => 
    array
      'id' => '7'
      'name' => 'Xbox 360'
      'games' => 1
```

I wanted to be sorted by the value of 'games' while respecting the order of sorted 'name' if the value of 'games' are the same.

The result should look like this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => '7'
      'name' => 'Xbox 360'
      'games' => 1
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => '1'
      'name' => 'Playstation 2'
      'games' => 2
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => '7'
      'name' => 'Playstation 3'
      'games' => 2
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => '4'
      'name' => 'iPad'
      'games' => 5
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => '5'
      'name' => 'iPhone'
      'games' => 5
  5 => 
    array
      'id' => '6'
      'name' => 'iPod Touch'
      'games' => 5
```

I've tried practically all sort functions and user-defined comparison function, but couldn't find the right one.

If it is possible, how can I approach it if I want 'games' DESC while maintaining the sorted 'name' ASC if the value of games are the same? Example:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => '6'
      'name' => 'Nintendo DS'
      'games' => 5
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => '5'
      'name' => 'iPhone'
      'games' => 5
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => '4'
      'name' => 'iPad'
      'games' => 5
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => '1'
      'name' => 'Playstation 2'
      'games' => 2
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => '7'
      'name' => 'Playstation 3'
      'games' => 2
  5 => 
    array
      'id' => '7'
      'name' => 'Xbox 360'
      'games' => 1
```

Comment: Are you pulling your data using mysql? You can use 2 order by's instead of doing it from php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['games'] == $b['games']) {
        return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    } else {
        return $a['games'] - $b['games'];
    }
});
```

Comment: I may have the ASC vs. DESC mixed up here, I always can't keep them straight... Reverse `$a` and `$b` if so.

Comment: It Works! I also replaced 'strcmp' with 'strcasecmp' since the lowercase 'i' in iPhone and iPod will mess up the order. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are other approaches using custom comparison functions, but the simplest approach is with [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

First create arrays with the keys by which you want to sort your array. Then supply those arrays with the sorting parameters to `array_multisort`.

```php
// first collect the sorting keys
// ensure that $thearray[$n]['key'] corresponds to $sortkey[$n]
$games = array();
$name = array();
foreach ($thearray as $item) {
    $games = $item['games'];
    $name = $item['name'];
}

// now sort
array_multisort($games, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC,
                $name, SORT_STRING, SORT_ASC,
                $thearray);
// $thearray is now sorted first by games, then by name.
```